# App not responding to a sms message received unless app is running.

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have an app that basically has two receivers, one that receives SMS messages and one that receives MMS messages.  When the app is running, it works perfectly, messages are received and the receivers both work.  When not running, the app receivers are not called.

Here is the basic code in the SMSReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    Log.i(TAG, "Intent received: " + intent.getAction());
    Toast.makeText(context,"Message Received SMS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Manifest permissions all there and correct.  Running a Samsung S7 Edge Android 7.0 (Android 24).  It should receive the texts no matter what, even if not running or in background.

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.webnation.text2email.receivers.SMSBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
           <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.webnation.text2email.receivers.MMSBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: You're probably missing the ```exported``` attribute in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Service` and pass the `intent` over to it instead of handling it with `onReceive()`. Also the `context` param from the `onReceive()` cannot be used to do UI actions, but it can be used to start an `Activity` or a `Service`.

Here's an example of how the implementation will  be for the `onReceive()`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
        Logger.LogI(TAG, "onReceive: received sms");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(intent);
        serviceIntent.setClassName(context, SmsParserService.class.getCanonicalName());
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

And here's an example for the implementation for the `SmsParserService`:

```
/**
 * Service for parsing the SMS and retrieving the message
 */
public class SmsParserService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = SmsParserService.class.getSimpleName();

    public SmsParserService() {
        this("SmsParserService");
    }

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public SmsParserService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            Object[] objects = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

            if (objects != null) {
                for (Object object : objects) {
                    SmsMessage smsMessage;
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) object, extras.getString("format"));
                    } else {
                        smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) object);
                    }

                    String message = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".services.SmsReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name=".services.SmsParserService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
</service>
```

Also remember that a `Service` is a background process, meaning some UI elements (like `Dialog` and `Toast`) might not work as well. Instead you should use an `Activity` for such cases.

Comment: It's never even calling onReceive(), so your suggestion won't even be called. The Toast is never displayed. In addition, with Oreo, running things in a service going forward may not be the way to go.    https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c

Comment: I've updated the answer with the ```AndroidManifest.xml``` entries. You are porbably not receiving due the entries you are using. If ```Service``` does not suite you due to having to support Android Oreo, I believe then you should use the ```Activity```, but I haven't tried starting a ```Service``` from within ```Receiver``` in Oreo and also the article does not state anything about that

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out?